# Clean code: How to refactor code to make it better removing the switch statement

Tags: c#

I have the following code on my game:

```
public class EnemyCount : MonoBehaviour
{
public EnemyType et;
void Start()
{
    int value=0;
    switch(et){
        case EnemyType.Warrior:
            value = increasePlayerPrefs(Constantes.WARRIORS_KILLED);
            achievementChecker(value, Constantes.WARRIOR_KILLER_ACHIEVEMENT, 20);
            break;
        case EnemyType.Mage:
            value = increasePlayerPrefs(Constantes.MAGES_KILLED);
            achievementChecker(value, Constantes.MAGE_KILLER_ACHIEVEMENT, 20);
            break;
        case EnemyType.BigKnight:
            value = increasePlayerPrefs(Constantes.BIG_KNIGHTS_KILLED);
            achievementChecker(value, Constantes.BIG_KNIGHT_KILLER_ACHIEVEMENT, 10);
            break;
        case EnemyType.Ranger:
            value = increasePlayerPrefs(Constantes.RANGERS_KILLED);
            achievementChecker(value, Constantes.RANGER_KILLER_ACHIEVEMENT, 20);
            break;
        case EnemyType.StrongWarrior:
            value = increasePlayerPrefs(Constantes.STRONG_WARRIORS_KILLED);
            achievementChecker(value, Constantes.STRONG_WARRIOR_KILLER_ACHIEVEMENT, 20);
            break;
        case EnemyType.Sorcerer:
            value = increasePlayerPrefs(Constantes.SORCERERS_KILLED);
            achievementChecker(value, Constantes.SORCERER_KILLER_ACHIEVEMENT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log("Inimigo não identificado");
            break;
            
    }

    
}

public int increasePlayerPrefs(string StringConstant){
    int val = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(StringConstant);
    val = val + 1;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(StringConstant,val);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    Debug.Log(StringConstant+" value: "+val);
    return val;
}

public void achievementChecker(int enemiesKilled, string achievementConstant, int enemiesKilledToEnableAchievement){
    if( enemiesKilled >= enemiesKilledToEnableAchievement ){
        if(SteamManager.Initialized){
            SteamUserStats.SetAchievement (achievementConstant);
            SteamUserStats.StoreStats ();           
            Debug.Log("achievement complete: "+achievementConstant);
        }
    }
}


}
```

This code works, but I am learning Clean Code from "Uncle Bob" and he says that switches and if-else statements are evil because they break.

How can I change this code to make it better, using a "Clean code" approach?

I guess Polymorphism is the answer, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: When "Uncle Bob" claims `if`-else and `switch` statements are evil, doesn't he give an alternative?

Comment: The point here is not about "evilness of switch becasue they break" (in C#, it won't compile if there is no break). But yes, it seems not "right" because you're typing too much. The problem here is that it lacks "extensibility". The main architecture change would be to rpovide these "associations" through _data_ (for instance an XML file), that would allow to change or add new values without change to the code, and would permit modding (main game has a XML file declaring those associations, and a mod could replace it).

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi Uncle Bob says that Polymorphism is the answer. But I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: don't take those general "clean code" from uncle bob too directly. Especially in game development.

I would say that "indirection" would be a better answer, as a start. I mean, the call to "`increasePlayerPrefs`" and `achievementChecker` is repeated. First you want to switch only on what changes : the parameters. Then you call the functions once. Second, I would find a way to maybe write a dictionary with EnemyType as key and the relevant parameters as value, that would "feel" more clean to me.

Comment: Google for 'Polymorhpism',find a site where they explain stuff (like: https://stackify.com/oop-concept-polymorphism/ ) start reading and, after reading, come back to ask a smart question about 'Polymorphism'.... (BTW it's on my long-list to start reading something like that too )

Comment: @Pac Can you give me an example of how you did that in your game?

Comment: Let it go if it is not a bottleneck. The .NET CLR is much clever we think. Don't worry about expectable performance issues in the beginning of the development. Because the .NET CLR already know about them. Profiling first and try optimize.

Comment: @donggas90 I don't worry about performance at this moment. I am just trying to use something that I learn now. The game is almost complete. Only need some small fixes. But your idea of profiling and optimize is good. I will try it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe switches and/or if/else's are inherently evil. They have their place in properly structured code.

But, how you are using in your example is probably not the best way to tackle what you want to accomplish. Imagine adding a new character class. You'd have to find everywhere you did a switch case or if/else and make sure to account for that.

You need to look in to polymorphism, a common OOP pattern.

For example:

```
public abstract class BasePlayerClass
{
    protected abstract EnemyType EnemyType {get;}
    public int IncreaseKilledPlayerPrefs()
    {
        // note: this code should be protected with thread synchronization
        var val = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(EnemyType.ToString());
        val = val + 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(EnemyType.ToString(),val);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log(EnemyType.ToString()+" value: "+val);
        return val;
    }
}

public sealed class Mage : BasePlayerClass
{
    protected override EnemyType EnemyType => EnemyType.Mage;
}

public sealed class Warrior : BasePlayerClass
{
    protected override EnemyType EnemyType => EnemyType.Warrior;
}
```

So now when a Mage gets killed, you'd call `theMage.IncreaseKilledPlayerPrefs()`

You don't need to iterate through all the object types, because you already know the object type and the object can update everything itself. Then when you add a new player-class, you just create the new class, add the new enum and you are done.

*Now, I'm not saying this is how you should do this, by any means*. I am showing you how polymorphism can help you think more abstractly about the objects in your game and avoid iterating through types.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I am looking for. But I just didn't understand why the method "IncreaseKilledPlayerPrefs" should be protected with thread synchronization.

Comment: This actually should happen in PlayerPrefs.SetInt(). If 2 threads try to call that method at the same time, you could have a race condition. So you would surround that code with a `lock`. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement