# Avoiding switch statements nth time

Tags: java, c#, oop, switch-statement

One argument that is often made concerning avoiding switch statements is that if there is a change/addition, you will have to look all over your code where in your code switch statements are that are effected by a new choice. (and you might forget to change one).

That sounds interesting, but if I use other constructs like function pointers (jump tables) like here:

[https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals][1]

or here

[https://simpleprogrammer.com/refactoring-switches-to-classes/][1]

I will have the same problem in adapting those when new choices are required.
So.. if I have switches/choices at all,  what is the best choice to implement the "Open/Closed principle"?

The only way I see is instead of using

```
switch(person.position){

case "manager":
break;

case "worker":
break;

case: "temp"
....
```

is to feed the whole Person object for "John Smith" into a function where then the appropriate functions will be invoked.
The switch statement will be in the class:

```
class Person {
...
...

public void applyBonus(){
    switch (this.position) {
    
    case "manager": this.addBonus(10000)
    break;
    }

}
```

If now any changes are requested it's only in the "Person" class.

Do I get this right?

Comment: Still if another `Position` is added, you would have to change the source code (i.e. the `switch`-statement). Another (more flexible) approach would be to, e.g.,  use a [Chain-of-responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern), in which one can dynamically register new handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195047/clean-code-how-to-refactor-code-to-make-it-better-removing-the-switch-statement/63195646#63195646) (but in C#). Your `Person` could be abstract and force classes that implement the `Person` class to define it's `bonus` amount. Then your base class could simply implement a `applyBonus`. For example:

```
public abstract class Person
{
  protected double salary, bonusAmount, baseSalary;
  
  protected Person(double baseSalary, double bonusAmount)
  {
    this.baseSalary = baseSalary;
    this.bonusAmount = bonusAmount;
  }
  
  public void applyBonus()
  {
    salary += bonusAmount;
  }
}

public final class Manager extends Person {
  public Manager()
  {
    super(100000.0, 1000.0);
  }
}

public final class Worker extends Person {
  public Worker()
  {
    super(10000.0, 500.0);
  }
}

public final class TempWorker extends Person {
  public TempWorker()
  {
    super(1000.0, 200.0);
  }
}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
var myTeam = new Person[] { new Manager(), new Worker(), new Worker(), new TempWorker() };
// apply bonuses:
for(var member : myTeam){
    member.applyBonus();
}
```

*Now, I'm not saying this is how you should do this, by any means*. I am showing you how polymorphism and other OOP patterns can help you think more abstractly about the objects in your program and avoid iterating through types.